# Sentence meaning Similarity and frequency

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have got a set of verbatims/sentences and what I am trying to do is ....if two sentences have the same meaning, those sentences should be replaced by the original one and later on,I got to take the frequency of such sentences.

Is there a way I can do it in NLTK? Any suggestions in this regard are welcome and appreciated.
I am looking for NLP approach.
Thanks

Comment: See http://ixa2.si.ehu.es/stswiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using some more up-to-date ideas for word/document embeddings for sentence similarity, such as:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/modules/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1
- https://github.com/facebookresearch/StarSpace - recently this implementation has been added to RASA NLU - https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/embedding_intent_classifier.py
- https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet-numberbatch
- http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2017/task1/ - it's annual competition related to NLP tasks, Semantic Textual Similarity is also there. It could be a really nice source of ideas for you.

On the one hand, sentence embeddings could be used to compare sentences easily, on the other hand, you have word embeddings that could be averaged/summed up to get a whole sentence embedding. To compare sentence vectors metrics such as cosine similarity could be used.

Answer (score 1):

I found some papers that might be able to give you a few ideas on how to solve this problem. They use WordNet, which is a corpus that can be used for checking similarity of words, and it is available on NLTK:

1. Corley, Courtney, and Rada Mihalcea. "Measuring the semantic similarity of texts." Proceedings of the ACL workshop on empirical modeling of semantic equivalence and entailment. Association for Computational Linguistics, 2005.
   --> translates word-to-word similarity at a text level and I believe you can adapt it for sentences. (https://aclanthology.info/pdf/W/W05/W05-1203.pdf)
2. Honeck, Richard P. "Semantic similarity between sentences." Journal of psycholinguistic research 2.2 (1973): 137-151. --> Here is another paper that calculates similarity scores between sentences.

I only skimmed the two papers, but it seems that the first paper uses syntactic and semantic similarity techniques sequentially whereas the second one uses them parallelly.

3. Miller, George A., and Walter G. Charles. "Contextual correlates of semantic similarity." Language and cognitive processes 6.1 (1991): 1-28. --> This is a linguistics paper which might give you a better understanding on how to compare the semantic similarity of sentences in case the first two methods do not work out for you, and you have to come up with your own solution.

Good luck and hope this helps!

Comment: Wordnet might be a bad idea for "word" similarity.